# e.target is undefined React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm still very novice to react and trying to learn how to authenticate with firebase.

I am using the Reshaped UI library which can be found here: [Reshaped Documentation](https://reshaped.so/content/docs/getting-started/overview)

This is my current code for the sign in page.

```
import {
  Button,
  Reshaped,
  View,
  useTheme,
  Frame,
  Text,
  Container,
  FormControl,
  TextField,
  Checkbox,
  Divider,
} from "reshaped";
import "reshaped/themes/reshaped/theme.css";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { FcGoogle } from "react-icons/fc";
import { useState } from "react";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import toast, { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";

function SignIn() {
  return (
    <Reshaped theme="reshaped">
      <Frame>
        <SignPanel />
      </Frame>
    </Reshaped>
  );
}

let test;

const SignPanel = () => {
  const { setColorMode } = useTheme();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const notify = () => toast.error("Try again later.");

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      console.log("User signed in successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      notify();
    }
  };

  let dark = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;
  if (dark) {
    setColorMode("dark");
  } else {
    setColorMode("light");
  }
  return (
    <Reshaped theme="reshaped">
      <Toaster />
      <View position={"absolute"} insetTop={4} insetEnd={4} zIndex={1000}>
        <Link to="/sign-up" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
          <Button rounded variant="outline">
            Sign up
          </Button>
        </Link>
      </View>
      <Frame height="100vh" justify={"center"}>
        <Container width={"400px"}>
          <center>
            <Text variant="title-1">Sign in</Text>
            <View height={2} />
            <Text>
              Welcome back! If you've got an account with us, please sign in
              below.
            </Text>
          </center>
          <View height={3} />
          <FormControl onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FormControl.Label>Email</FormControl.Label>
            <TextField
              name="email"
              placeholder="Enter your email"
              required
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <View height={2} />
            <FormControl.Label>Password</FormControl.Label>
            <TextField
              name="password"
              placeholder="Enter your password"
              inputAttributes={{ type: "password" }}
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
            <View height={5} />
            <Checkbox
              name="keepSigned"
              defaultChecked={false}
              disabled={false}
              hasError={false}
              indeterminate={false}
            >
              Keep me signed in
            </Checkbox>
            <View height={5} />
            <Button fullWidth color="primary" loading={test} type="submit">
              Sign in
            </Button>
            <View height={3} />
            <center>
              <Link to={"/forgot"}>Forgot password?</Link>
            </center>
          </FormControl>
          <View height={4} />
          <Divider />
          <View height={4} />
          <Button
            variant="outline"
            fullWidth
            startIcon={FcGoogle}
            loading={test}
          >
            Sign in with Google
          </Button>
        </Container>
      </Frame>
    </Reshaped>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

Any time I type text into the textboxes, it says `e.target is undefined`

I'm not sure what to do. Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [TextField documentation page](https://reshaped.so/content/docs/components/text-field/props) you need to destructure `event` from onChange function:
`(args: { event, name, value }): void`:

```
  <TextField
              name="email"
              placeholder="Enter your email"
              required
              value={email}
              onChange={({event}) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
            />
```